# web develop + usb notification

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, notifications

In a local area network is lamp-server, on which the site is located. On the client computers (winXP, Ubuntu) network running opera / firefox (mode kioskmode).

> Opera-kioskmode local_site.ru.dev

Is it possible to doing what any script / code local_site.ru.dev - access usb devices (flash drive, SD card and other drives) connected to client computers? Accordingly, pressing or not pressing any buttons on it local_site.ru.dev
The web camera to connect without problems.

Using any web programming technology, you can make it happen.
Need versatility regardless of platform Win | Lin
I would be very grateful for the detailed response.

Answer (score 1):

You're requirement is not so clear, but in order to access a physical drives on client machine, You may need technologies like; **Silverlight (Moonlight - on Linux)**, or **Adobe Air**, etc.

Or, You also can use ActiveX which is a traditional way do so what such a thing you need.

However, if your requirement to develop an application where to deploy-once and use from many clients, then why don't you try **Out-Of-Browser** Silverlight + Auto Update.

Here is the link - http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-offline-update-framework.aspx

Cheers!

Comment: local network I have 40 client computers after installing the USB media and download files from it, every customer through the process of placing the order. After processing returns to the screen local_site.ru.dev
At one time the client connects to the computer one carrier, after the procedure of placing the order, the next, etc.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, I would say your application will be some kinds of blocking user to do something else. so, please ignore my answer and move back to what you try to do with Windows Application + Citrix. Good luck.